# How do I get the keys from an association list? scheme/ racket

Tags: list, scheme, racket, associative-array

how do I get the keys from an association list?
I.E  (

```
define lst1 (list(list 2 "three")(list 2 "two")(list 1 "one")))
       (get-keys lst1) => (list 2 2 1)
```

the below is what I wrote:

```
(define(get-keys alst)
  (cond
    [(empty? alst) empty]
    [(number?(first(first alst)))(cons(first(first alst))(get-keys (rest alst)))]
    [else(get-keys (rest alst))]))
```

however this is highly inneficient when I try and use get-keys as a helper function..What I am really trying to do is write a program that consumes two association lists and returns only the keys that do not repeat.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a really simple solution, using built-in higher-order procedures (don't reinvent the wheel!):

```
(define (get-keys alst)
  (map first alst))
```

The above procedure *maps* the `first` procedure over the input list, that is: it takes the first element from each association. If at some point you need to delete duplicate keys, then use `remove-duplicates`, for example:

```
(define lst1 (list (list 2 "three") (list 2 "two") (list 1 "one")))
(remove-duplicates (get-keys lst1))
=> '(2 1)
```

Alternatively, if you're note allowed to use `map` we can always write a procedure from scratch using only primitive operations, like this:

```
(define (get-keys alst)
  (cond
    [(empty? alst) empty]
    [else (cons (first (first alst))
                (get-keys (rest alst)))]))
```

Comment: It might be better to use `(map car alst)`, since association lists are frequently just lists of pairs, not lists of lists, and Racket's `first` is restricted to work on lists (it doesn't work on any old pair). Still, +1, obviously the right approach. :)

Comment: Thanks for ur help, I see what you are saying, however I am not allowed to use map

Comment: I am using beginning student with list abbrevisations

Comment: @dd123 ok, I added an implementation from scratch, look at the end of my solution. If this is what you needed, please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer, simply click on the check mark to its left ;)